# Javascript Help - Game Of Nim

Tags: javascript, simplify

i am new to coding and im working on a project for a java script course that i need a bit of help with. I have to make a small game called Nim it has simple rules and and I've pretty much got a working game but i need to make the computer more challenging without changing the number of pile or stones. it is too easy to win. I barley figured out how to make it work and im not sure what i could do to make it more challenging. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Quick explanation:3 piles of 5 stones each.
displayed as: "Pile A ooooo, Pile B ooooo, Pile C ooooo"
The player and computer take turns removing stones by entering pile letter and amount of stones.(Ex: B4, A2, C3) The last to pule stones loses.

```
function pile(name, stones) {
  this.name = name;
  this.stones = stones;
  display = function(name, stones) {
    console.log(this.name + " " + this.stones);
  }
}
var pileA = new pile("A", "ooooo");
var pileB = new pile("B", "ooooo");
var pileC = new pile("C", "ooooo");

function displayBoard() {
  console.log("Game OF NIM!");
  console.log(pileA, pileB, pileC);
}

function yourMove() {
  displayBoard();
  var moveData = prompt("Enter the letter of the pile and the number of stones to take.\n " 
    + "Ex.B5 or A2 ");
    if (moveData[0] == 'A') {
      var x = pileA.stones.length - moveData[1];
      pileA.stones = pileA.stones.slice(0, x);
      return pileA.stones;
    } else if (moveData[0] == 'B') {
      var x = pileB.stones.length - moveData[1];
      pileB.stones = pileB.stones.slice(0, x);
      return pileB.stones;
    } else if (moveData[0] == 'C') {
      var x = pileC.stones.length - (moveData[1] + 1);
      pileC.stones = pileC.stones.slice(0, x);
      return pileC.stones;
    }
  }

  function computersMove() {
    displayBoard();
    alert("Now it is the computer's turn!");
    if (pileA.stones != "") {
      pileA.stones = pileA.stones.slice(0, 0);
      return pileA.stones;
    } else if (pileB.stones != "") {
      pileB.stones = pileB.stones.slice(0, 0);
      return pileB.stones;
    } else if (pileC.stones != "") {
      pileC.stones = pileC.stones.slice(0, 0);
      return pileC.stones;
    }
    if (pileA.stones == "" && pileB.stones == "" && pileC.stones == "") {
      console.log("Computer Wins!!!");
    }
  }
  while (pileA.stones != "" || pileB.stones != "" || pileC.stones != "") {
    yourMove();
    if (pileA.stones == "" && pileB.stones == "" && pileC.stones == "") {
      console.log("You win!!!");
    }
    if (pileA.stones != "" || pileB.stones != "" || pileC.stones != "") {
      computersMove();
    }
  }
  alert('Game Over!');
```

Comment: While this is an interesting question, it is not the focus of Stack Overflow.  You might want to try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ or http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ (I don't know anything about them but they looked similar).

Comment: Im new to coding and coding forums / sites this one was recommended by a friend who codes but ill try that one. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Game of Nim' has [a simple deterministic solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim#Mathematical_theory). The following algorithm computes the optimal move given an array of stacks / piles / heaps:

```js
// Returns the optimal move or undefined if no winning move is possible:
function optimal_move(stacks) {
  var stacks_xor = stacks.reduce((r, e) => r ^ e, 0);
  var is_endgame = stacks.reduce((r, e) => r + (e > 1), 0) < 2;
  var move = stacks.reduce((move, stack, i) => {
    var take = stack - (is_endgame ^ stack ^ stacks_xor);
    return take > move[1] ? [i, take] : move;
  }, [0, 0]);
  return move[1] > 0 ? move : undefined;
}

console.log(optimal_move([3, 4, 5])); // [0, 2] 'remove 2 from stack 0'
```

If no winning move is possible, I suggest you perform random moves until the human player errs.

To make the game more entertaining, a certain percentage (depending on the difficulty) of moves would be randomly chosen instead of optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to coding I guess machine learning is not a suitable solution :-) You can either try to code behaviors for certain scenarios like  this (pseudo):

```
if (A.empty() AND B.empty()) {
    remove all but 1 from C;
}
```

or you can try to add some randomization so the computer will be less predictable. With randomization I mean randomizing the amount of stones that the computer removes each time and also randomizing which pile it picks from. In my opinion you should also add a maximum amount of stones that can be removed at a time, let's say 3 for example.